# How to get distinct name and count in MongoDB using PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have the below collection as shown below. All I want is the distinct "Name" and the count. For example Betty appears 2 times, so the output I want is Betty:2, Vic:1, Veronica:2. I am able to get the distinct Name by issuing the command "**db.Car.find().distinct('Name')**" but not sure how to get the count.

```
{
    "Name": "Betty",
    "Car": "Jeep",
}
{
    "Name": "Betty",
    "Car": "Van",
}
{
    "Name": "Vic",
    "Car": "Ferrari",
}
{
    "Name": "Veronica",
    "Car": "Bus",
}
{
    "Name": "Veronica",
    "Car": "Van",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count all unique values In MONGODB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220321/how-to-count-all-unique-values-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `$group` to group by `Name` field and use `$sum` operator in it to get the `Count` field.

Something like below:

```py
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Name",
      "Count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Name": "$_id",
      "Count": 1,
      "_id":0
    }
  }
])
```

The above will produce the following output:

```
[
  {
    "Count": 2,
    "Name": "Betty"
  },
  {
    "Count": 1,
    "Name": "Vic"
  },
  {
    "Count": 2,
    "Name": "Veronica"
  }
]
```